# Jackson objectMapper mapping different json properties to same pojo

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a very simple json which I am trying to map to an object.

JSON :

```json
[
    {
        "cust_lpid": "0119b9f7f99ad2161de7b0b",
        "cust_uid": "soumavtestflow"
    }
]
```

My Mapper Class:

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class CustomerSegmentRequest {

    @JsonProperty("LPID")
    String cust_lpid;
    @JsonProperty("UserId")
    String cust_uid;

    public String getCust_lpid() {
        return cust_lpid;
    }
    public void setCust_lpid(String cust_lpid) {
        this.cust_lpid = cust_lpid;
    }
    public String getCust_uid() {
        return cust_uid;
    }
    public void setCust_uid(String cust_uid) {
        this.cust_uid = cust_uid;
    }
}
```

When I do a

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
LPIDCustIDMapper[] custSegResp = objectMapper.readValue(responseBody,CustomerSegmentRequest [].class);
```

I don't get any values populated in custSegResp.

However when i remove the `@JsonProperty` it works.
I need the json property name to map an incoming request and hence don't wanna create a separate mapping class.
Is there a way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [@JsonAlias](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9.pr3/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAlias.html)

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class CustomerSegmentRequest {

   @JsonAlias({"cust_lpid", "LPID" })
   String cust_lpid;

   @JsonAlias({"cust_uid", "UserId" })
   String cust_uid;

   public String getCust_lpid() {
      return cust_lpid;
   }

   public void setCust_lpid(String cust_lpid) {
      this.cust_lpid = cust_lpid;
   }

    public String getCust_uid() {
      return cust_uid;
   }

    public void setCust_uid(String cust_uid) {
       this.cust_uid = cust_uid;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`@JsonProperty("keyName")` is to specify what is the `key` is the JSON which maps to this field.

The reason it works without it is, without it Jackson tries to first match via getters/setters after removing the `get`/`set` prefix keys and normalizing the case (`getAbCd` -> `abCd`), which in your case gives the keys as in the JSON.

You need to modify your `@JsonProperty("LPID")` to  `@JsonProperty("cust_lpid")` or if you need to map to multiple keys use [`@JsonAlias({"cust_lpid", "LPID" })`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9.pr3/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAlias.html)